# WordPress and Reactjs for complex solution?

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

My question is "simple", can we create a complex website with WordPress and Reactjs for a company which has a lot of iot devices with multiple pieces of data? This company needs also a client area where clients can have their dashboard, contracts and a bunch of information collected from those iot devices.

Or maybe WordPress isn't the best solution for this kind of website?
Thank you in advance for any help you can provide me.

Answer (score 0):

as I am new to StackOverflow as well I will let you know that questions like this are not for this site. You might want to check out StackExchange to find this answer. https://stackexchange.com